# Preload has_one association in a case insensitive manner

Tags: elixir, mariadb, phoenix-framework, ecto

We're currently in the process of migrating from Ruby/Rails/MariaDB to Elixir/Phoenix/MariaDB and I've come across an issue when preloading an association in Ecto that we didn't see with ActiveRecord.

We have some relationships defined in our Rails project that have foreign keys of type string (not best practice, I know). For example, an account has one billing plan (as defined in the new Elixir project):

```
schema "accounts" do
  field(:name, :string)
  field(:email_address, :string)
  field(:active, :boolean)
  field(:billing_model, :string)
  has_one(:billing_plan, BillingPlan, foreign_key: :name, references: :billing_model)
end

schema "billing_plans" do
  field(:name, :string)
  field(:price, :integer)
end
```

The problem occurs when there is a case mismatch, for example if the account has `Pro` stored as the `billing_model` but the `billing_plans` table has it as `pro`. When I attempt the preload the association like this: `Repo.get(Account, 1234) |> Repo.preload(:billing_plan)`, Ecto returns `nil` for the `billing_plan`. Whereas, if the cases match up, Ecto returns the `billing_plan` as expected.

My initial thought was to fix this in the database such that the cases match up. However, this did not work as new examples began to occur and I realised this was not a problem unique to this association - there are many relationships like this in our schema. This is why I would like to fix this at a higher level so it does not come back to bite us later. Ideally, it would be good to pass a flag to the DB config or an option when defining the association.

Has anyone come across this issue before that could offer a nudge in the right direction or a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you have string foreign keys that does not match because of the Upper/Lower Case.

What about if instead of doing a preload you build your own query, I can not test the case but it should be something like

```
(from a in Account, join: b in BillingPlan, where: a.billing_model == 1234 and a.billing_model == b.name, select: %{ a | billing_plan: b}) |> Repo.one()
```

Before doing this you sould import Ecto.Query.

I hope it works.